# Using globals in functional tests (with Symfony and Codeception)

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, codeception, symfony-kernel

I want to test  this function:

```
static protected function getContainerInterface()
{
    global $kernel;
    if (get_class($kernel) == 'AppCache') {
        /** @var \AppCache $cache */
        $cache = $kernel;
        $kernel = $cache->getKernel();
    }
    return $kernel->getContainer();
}
```

And got an error: 
Call to a member function getContainer() on null 
triggered by this string:

```
return $kernel->getContainer();
```

How can I pass global $kernel object to crawler( that is instance of FunctionalTester) in codeception ?

Comment: Is this a method called "interface"? This is not an interface. An interface is a keyword in PHP and shouldn't be used like this at all.

Comment: Joe, I agree. Thanks for advice. I'm 'enjoying myself' rewriting legacy project and there are many interesting things, such an 'interface caller' is only one in a long row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global variable is a bad practice. I can assume that when running tests, codeception creates its own test kernel and this kernel can not be used globally. This place needs to be refactored

Comment: It's good idea to refactor legacy code and clean it from any globals